# cannot grant any permissions to db2 database

Tags: db2

I cannot change any permissions in one of my db2 databases because the db2 instance is not authorized

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0551N  The statement failed because the authorization ID does not have the 
required authorization or privilege to perform the operation.
```

I tried to grant administrative permissions for that user but it doesn't have grant permissions either

Do you know any command to check which users have permissions to that database?

Regards

Comment: What is your Db2-*server* platform ? ( Z/OS or  i-series or Linux/Unix/Windows)

Comment: @mao it is a Linux RedHat6

Comment: @user485903 What's the exact statement you tried?

Comment: db2 grant dbadm on database to user db2instx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the password for the instance-owner (e.g. db2instx) for connecting to the database, or if you can su/sudo to the instance-owner on the Db2-server, then that instance owner account can grant other users the dbadm (and some other) database rights, and the user with SECADM role can grant additional permissions.

This is not a programming question, but instead an administration question, and the Db2 documentation covers this topic well. So do your study.

Refer to the documentation for details of the [GRANT (database)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000958.html) statement 
Also study the [GRANT statement for table/views](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000966.html) 
along with other types of GRANT statement for other types of objects.

Study the role of SECADM, if such a role is defined, if your Db2-server version is modern. If your site uses ROLES  in addition to other security mechanisms, you also need to be familiar with those.

To find your own account rights you can either query the catalog views (if you have permission, such as (syscat.tabauth,  syscat.dbauth and others tc.) or call the table function [AUTH_LIST_AUTHORITIES_FOR_AUTHID](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0052898.html) from the CLP after connecting.